# Azure deployed django app not displaying media files on Vuejs frontend in prooduction

Tags: python, django, azure, vue.js, django-storage

These are the packages that I am using:

```
Django==3.2
django-storages==1.12.3
```

I am trying to deploy a django REST API with Vuejs frontend on azure. This is my directory structure for the django API.

[image]

I have used djang-storages[azure] to use an azure container blob to store media files. I went through a tutorial to setup the blob connection with django. Some configuration that I did with settings.py are these

**Settings.py**

```py
MEDIA_LOCATION = "media"

AZURE_ACCOUNT_NAME = "my account name"
AZURE_ACCOUNT_KEY="my token"
AZURE_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = f'{AZURE_ACCOUNT_NAME}.blob.core.windows.net'
AZURE_LOCATION="media"
AZURE_CONTAINER="media"

STATIC_LOCATION = "static"
STATIC_URL = f'https://{AZURE_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{STATIC_LOCATION}/'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.azure_storage.AzureStorage'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'el.custom_azure.AzureMediaStorage'
AZURE_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_SECS=100
```

and my custom_azure.py looks like this:

**custom_azure.py**

```py
from storages.backends.azure_storage import AzureStorage

class AzureMediaStorage(AzureStorage):
    account_name="eltechstorage"
    account_key="my token"
    azure_container="media"
    expiration_specs=None
```

**urls.py**

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import  staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("",include("main.urls"))
]
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

When I am using azure blob container to upload media files it is working perfectly in development environment and when I am testing the API from the deployed url, it is giving me the path of the file as expected on which if i go to, downloads the file for me, everything is working perfect. Below is attached a sample response from the API.
[image]

**The Problem**

But when I use the deployed version of both Django and Vuejs App, and I open the page, where the API returns the object containing link to the file. it displays a 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

according to [django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#static-file-development-view) doc, the static helper is only workable in debug mode. therefore, in your production environment, if you don't have debug mode enabled, then you static view will not be there. as a temporary measure, you can enable debug by put `DEBUG=True` in your application settings.
as recommendation by [django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#static-file-development-view), you should serve your static files in a dedicate server in production environment.

Comment: As guided by azure, I am serving static files an azure blob storage container, which acts as a dedicated server. My server is working fine with static files, but not with the media files.